# HTML CSS take as much height as possible

Tags: html, css, height, max

I have quite an interesting situation. I have a table with two columns. In The left one, I have a lot of text, it is HUGE. In the right column, I have a marquee with a very long list, longer still than the content in the left column, but, for it is a marquee, the height is quite little. Is it possible to set the marquees height to as much as it can possibly take without making an overflow?

```
<table>
<tr>
<td width="50%">
A long<br/>
long<br/>
long<br/>
...
long<br/>
text.
</td>
<td width="50%">
<marquee direction="up">
A much<br/>
much<br/>
much<br/>
...
much<br/>
longer text still.
</marquee>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

How is it possible to force that marquee take as much height as possible, e. g. `style="height: max;"`

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you found a solution? I have the same problem but I don't want to use javascript...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

try this style="height:auto;"